# How to save image created by PHP imagecopymerge function

Tags: php

### code:

```
$dest = @imagecreatefrompng(base_url().'assets/images/card-design-3-backside.png');
$src = @imagecreatefrompng(base_url().'assets/images/card-design-3-ackside.png);
$sj = imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 845, 280, 0, 0, 200, 200, 100);    
header('Content-Type: image/png');          
imagepng($dest);
imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save image to a file, just adding the 2nd parameter to the imagepng() function. Like this:

```
imagepng($dest, "file.png");
```

Don't need add a header because we don't want to output to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you mean save to disk or download. From the manual:

**SAVE TO DISK (On server):**

```
<?php
// Create a destination
$dest = 'new/spot/new_name.png';
// Get contents from original spot
$im = imagecreatefrompng("https://www.fagario.com/skins/by-hacker.png");
// Save to disk in the new spot and name
imagepng($im,$dest);
// Destroy image
imagedestroy($im);
```

**DOWNLOAD (to local):**

```
<?php
$dest   =   "name.png";
// Get contents from original spot
$im = imagecreatefrompng("https://www.fagario.com/skins/by-hacker.png");
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename='.$dest); 
// Create the proper file type header
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
// Destroy image
imagedestroy($im);
```

**PRESENT IN BROWSER (No download or saving):**

```
<?php
// Get contents from original spot
$im = imagecreatefrompng("https://www.fagario.com/skins/by-hacker.png");
// Create the proper file type header
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
// Destroy image
imagedestroy($im);
```