PHP imagecreatefrompng Present In Browser And Save As Functions
I prepared a project that adds the text in the textbox to the image. But there is a problem in this project.
Since the file is php, when I right click on the image and say save as, it saves it with the php extension. (if there is a way to change this extension it would be easier for me). For this reason, when the image is opened, I want the browser's "save as" window to appear and save it as text + .png file in the textbox. I was able to do this thanks to the answer in another question (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33315119/20978137), but this time I cannot view the image in the browser. How can I do these two at the same time?
Code:
<?php
// (A) BACKGROUND
$img = imagecreatefrompng("back.png");

// (B) TEXT AND FONT OPTIONS
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $txt = $_POST["metin"];
}
$fontFile = "C:\Windows\Fonts\gilroy-black_0.otf"; // SUNUCUYA YÜKLEYİNCE DEĞİŞTİR
$fontSize = 110;
$fontColor = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$angle = 0;

// (C) TEXT POSITION
// (C1) GET IMAGE DIMENSIONS
$iWidth = imagesx($img);
$iHeight = imagesy($img);

// (C2) GET TEXT BOX DIMENSIONS
$tSize = imagettfbbox($fontSize, $angle, $fontFile, $txt);
$tWidth = max([$tSize[2], $tSize[4]]) - min([$tSize[0], $tSize[6]]);
$tHeight = max([$tSize[5], $tSize[7]]) - min([$tSize[1], $tSize[3]]);

// (C3) CENTER THE TEXT BLOCK
$centerX = ceil(($iWidth - $tWidth) / 2);
$centerX = $centerX<0 ? 0 : $centerX;

// (D) DRAW TEXT ON IMAGE
imagettftext($img, $fontSize, $angle, $centerX, 950, $fontColor, $fontFile, $txt);

// (E) OUTPUT IMAGE
$dest   =  $txt.".png";
header("Content-type: image/png");
header('Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename='.$dest); 

$outputFileName = 'ciktilar/'.$txt.'.png';

imagepng($img);
imagepng($img, $outputFileName);
imagedestroy($img);


Instead of Content-Disposition: Attachment; filename=..., try Content-Disposition: inline; filename=...

@CBroe not working.

Then you could either use URL rewriting, or maybe wrap the result into a link with the download attribute set - but both won't be easily applicable, as long as you are POSTing the data to this script. The context in which you need this "feature" is a bit unclear here - could you rewrite this, so that it gets the text passed via GET instead?

@CBroe So, what exactly should I do?

Use URL rewriting to present your URL using a .png extension instead of .php.

First of all, you should explain in what context you actually need this. Right now, you open the image on its own, based on data POSTed to the script - does it have to work this way? You could instead for example embed this into a HTML page via img, passing the necessary text data in the URL path already, and with the suffix .png - and then use URL rewriting, to get that request routed to your PHP script.
